# Sales Force Integration

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to integrate sales force with my application,I'm using oauth2.0 authorization for getting refresh token.I'm redirecting to salesforce login page.I dnt want to show this page in my app.Is there any way for that.

Answer (score 0):

The key concept behind using the [OAuth 2.0 Web Server Authentication Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US) or the [OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US) is that the users authentication details **only** go to Salesforce. Your application doesn't need to handle their username or password. This, combined with the authorization of your app in Salesforce gives the user a greater level of security.

You can't store the username/password details and they can revoke authorization access for the app.

If you don't want to redirect via the Salesforce login page you can use the [OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US). Here you will handle the username and password (plus potentially the security token). This is less secure from the users perspective, but bypasses the redirect to the Salesforce login page.

Incidentally, there is a [dedicated StackExchange site for Salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) that is a great place to ask these sort of questions.